# osx 1password cannot fill item in google chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am using [Surge](http://surge.run/manual/) as my proxy software, then my 1password chrome extension suddenly can not fill in item automatically. I googled a lot, but not much help. My environment is OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

After googling a lot, finally I found 1password extension use `WebSocket` to communicate with `1Password Mini`, and [Surge](http://surge.run/manual/)'s default config has something wrong with `127.0.0.1` address. so I open `Network`, go to the `Advanced...` config page. add `127.0.0.1` to the `Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:`:

`192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 100.64.0.0/10, localhost, *.local, 127.0.0.1`

then restart your chrome

[image]

---

[2016/8/24 updated]

vi ~/.surge.conf

skip-proxy = 192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 100.64.0.0/10, localhost, *.local, `127.0.0.1`